# Vue component included in laravel blade is not rendering while using router-link?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.5, vue-router

I have such code in my app.blade.php file.

`<router-view name="popupAction"></router-view>
 @yield('content')`

and other blade files are extending the app.blade.php file.
while I am in other vue compoent without router-link 

i.e. http://localhost:9002/Billing#/ everything seems fine
 but when i use router-link and I am in page similar to 
 http://localhost:9002/Billing#/admin 

 content inside component popupAction is not rendered, but scripts are being executed like when I use console.log from the page its showing up in console. 
Am I missing something over here?

To get it more clear when I include component this way,
 `<router-view name="billingIndex"></router-view>`
 `<router-view></router-view>`
 Its working fine, 
 but when I include this code in a component 
`<router-link :to="{name: 'invoiceBasedOnFilter', params: {month:picker,status:'ALL',method:'eft'}}"> View Page </router-link>`
 Its not working in the page followed by the link.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: no there is no errors in console its just codes inside <template></template> is not rendering, but other things are fine. @Shuvojit